# Webchat Value Exchanging Issue on Botframework V4

Tags: botframework

I'm using Direct Line, MS Speech Service and the Webchat.js on bot running on Botframework V4.
I start the bot from a web page using webchat.js passing values to the back end app like that
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event 
Code used to instanciate the bot on web channel:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>FTD Bit_Bot</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #fff; background-image: url('img/FTDBackground.jpg');">
    <div id="chatbot" role="main"
         data-cb-width="320px"
         data-cb-height="400px"
         data-cb-border="1px solid #ededed"
         data-cb-border-radius="0px"
         data-cb-background-color="white"
         data-cb-position="fixed"
         data-cb-right="40px"
         data-cb-bottom="100px"
         data-cb-zIndex="1"
         data-cb-bubble-background="rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.15)"
         data-cb-bubble-from-user-background="#e22e2c"
         data-cb-bubble-from-user-text-color="white"
         data-cb-bubble-max-width="600"
         data-cb-bot-avatar-image="http://demo.radical-thinking.net/bella/microsoft/chat-assets/img/Chat-in-day-Workshop-Icon.png"
         data-cb-hide-send-box="false"
         data-cb-hide-upload-button="true"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color="#e22e2c"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-disabled="#CCC"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-focus="#333"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-hover="#333"
         data-cb-send-box-height="30"
         data-cb-suggested-action-text-color="black"
         data-cb-suggested-action-border="solid 2px #e22e2c"
         data-cb-suggested-action-height="30">
    </div>
    <!-- Include ajax library for speech service token request call -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include webchat client functionality (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) -->
    <!-- Change to the latest directory to stop the 'No renderer for this activity' error. However the avatar won't show -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        var chatbot = document.getElementById('chatbot');

        // Style modifications
        const styleOptions = {

            // Colors
            bubbleBackground: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleBackground,
            bubbleFromUserBackground: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleFromUserBackground,
            bubbleFromUserTextColor: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleFromUserTextColor,
            bubbleMaxWidth: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleMaxWidth), // maximum width of text message

            // Avatar
            botAvatarImage: chatbot.dataset.cbBotAvatarImage,
            userAvatarInitials: '',

            // Send box
            hideSendBox: JSON.parse(chatbot.dataset.cbHideSendBox),
            hideUploadButton: JSON.parse(chatbot.dataset.cbHideUploadButton),
            sendBoxButtonColor: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColor,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnFocus: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnFocus,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnHover: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnHover,
            sendBoxHeight: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxHeight),

            // Suggested actions
            suggestedActionTextColor: chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionTextColor,
            suggestedActionBorder: chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionBorder,
            suggestedActionHeight: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionHeight),

        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var chatbot = document.getElementById("chatbot");

        //style tag start
        var script = {
            id: 'chatbotStyle',
            type: 'text/css',
            style: document.createElement('style'),
            content: '@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,600"); ::-webkit-scrollbar{width:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background:#f1f1f1}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background:#888}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background:#555} #chatbot{ font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; position: fixed; right: 10px; bottom: 20px; text-align: center; } #chatbot img{ margin: auto; } #chatbot small{ display: block; font-size: 9px; } .initLaunchPad{ cursor: pointer; text-align: center; transition: .4s all; } .botHeader{min-height:40px;background:#ededed;border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;padding:4px} .botHeader img{float:left;width:32px;height:32px; border-radius:50%;background-color:#f9f9f9}.botHeader h5{float:left;padding:0!important;margin:4px 0 3px 6px} .botHeader h5 small{font-size: 12px;} .botHeader > div{width:40%;display:flex;align-items:center;text-align:left;height:32px} #botClose{cursor:pointer;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;padding:6px 8px;border-radius:4px;background-color:#e22e2c;color:#fff; } #botContainer{ display: none; border-radius: 8px; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; transition:.4s all; width: 310px; height: 420px; max-width:420px; max-height: 420px; margin-bottom: 4px; } #botBody{ height: 366px; } ',
            append: function () {
                this.style.type = this.type;
                this.style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.content));
                document.head.appendChild(this.style);
            }
        }; script.append();
        //style tag end

        //initLaunchPad started
        var initLaunchPad = document.createElement('div');
        initLaunchPad.classList.add('initLaunchPad');
        var initBotIcon = document.createElement('img');
        initBotIcon.src = "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4876/39891228293_13c532f352_o.gif";
        initBotIcon.width = 86;
        initLaunchPad.appendChild(initBotIcon);
        chatbot.appendChild(initLaunchPad);

        $(function getSpeechAuthToken() {
            var params = {
                // Request parameters
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken" + $.param(params),
                beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                    // Request headers
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "XXXXXX");
                },
                type: "POST",
                // Request body
                data: "{body}",
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    speechAuthToken = data;
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert("error");
                });
        });
        initBotIcon.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            initLaunchPad.style.display = "none";
            botContainer.style.display = "block";

            /*Call bot API*/
            (async function () {

                const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

                //Speech Service Token Generation
                const subscriptionKey = 'XXXXXX';
                const region = 'brazilsouth';
                let webSpeechPonyfillFactory;

                //Speech Service Setting
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                    credentials: {
                        authorizationToken: speechAuthToken,
                        region: region
                    }
                });

                //Direct-Line BotToken Generation
                const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'XXXXXX' } });
                const { token } = await res.json();

                window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
                    store,
                    userID: "User",
                    styleOptions,
                    locale: 'pt-BR',
                    selectVoice: (voices, activity) =>
                        activity.locale === 'pt-BR'
                            ? voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name))
                            : voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)) ||
                            voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)),
                    webSpeechPonyfillFactory
                }, document.getElementById('botBody'));
                document.querySelector('#botBody > *').focus();

                var mainTag = chatbot.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
                mainTag.style.borderTop = chatbot.dataset.cbBorder;
            })().catch(err => console.error(err));

            //Bot Message Exchange Setting 
            const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
                if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'userName',
                            value: Paul
                        }
                    });
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'userGenre',
                            value: male
                        }
                    });
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'activityName',
                            value: chatBotMission
                        }
                    });
                }
                return next(action);
            });

        //initLaunchPad ended

        var botContainer = document.createElement('div');
        botContainer.id = "botContainer";

        var botHeader = document.createElement('div');
        botHeader.classList.add('botHeader');

        var botClose = document.createElement('a');
        botClose.id = "botClose";
        botClose.innerText = "X";
        botClose.title = "Close";
        botHeader.innerHTML = "<div><img src='" + chatbot.dataset.cbBotAvatarImage + "'/> <h5>Bit_Bot <small>FTD Educação</small> </div></h5>";
        botHeader.appendChild(botClose);

        botClose.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            initLaunchPad.style.display = "";
            botContainer.style.display = "none";
            return false;
        });

        botContainer.appendChild(botHeader);

        var botBody = document.createElement('div');
        botBody.id = "botBody";
        botContainer.appendChild(botBody);

        var poweredBy = document.createElement('div');
        poweredBy.innerHTML = "<small>Powered by <img src='http://ainetw.com/img/icon.png' width=12 /> AI Networks</small>";

        chatbot.appendChild(botContainer);
        chatbot.appendChild(poweredBy);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code snippet of the bot sent data collection in my bot:

```
 public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var studentProfile = await _studentProfileAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new StudentProfile(), cancellationToken);
            DialogContext dc = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            //Bot Channel Message Exchange Collection 
            if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "userName")
            {   
                studentProfile.Name = turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString();                   
                studentName = turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString();
            }
            if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "userGenre")
            {
                studentProfile.Gender = turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString();
                conversationSessionID = turnContext.Activity.From.Id;
                if (conversationSessionID.ToLower() == "user")
                {
                    var myConversationSessionID = turnContext.Activity.Id;
                    if (myConversationSessionID.IndexOf("|") != -1)
                    {
                        conversationSessionID = myConversationSessionID.Substring(0, myConversationSessionID.IndexOf("|"));
                    }
                }
                studentGender = turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString();
        //Variables persistance on DB
                SessionVariable SessionVariable = new SessionVariable();
                SessionVariable.AddSessionVariable(BellaMain.GlobalVariable.SystemID, BellaMain.GlobalVariable.CustomerID, conversationSessionID, "StudentName", studentName, "StudentGender", studentGender, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0);
            }
            if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "activityName")
            {
                if (turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString().ToLower() =="atividade2")
                {
                    var message = $"**Olá {studentName}, bem vindo ao Quant Bot!**";
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(message);
                    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(Activity2MainDialog, "activity2MainDialog", cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    var message = $"**Olá {studentName}, bem vindo ao Quant Bot!**";
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(message);                    
                }
            }
```

The application works fine but when there is more than one user connected to it exchanged data gets mismatched many times e.g. 
Webclient 1 sends user name: Paul and Gender: male ==> app receives Paul and male
Webclient 2 sends user name: Mary and Gender: female ==> app sometimes receives Paul and male !? It should receive Mary and female instead
I have a feeling the sent data is buffered on Azure or somewhere else and needs to be cleared/refreshed every time a new web app bot instance starts.
Does it make sense? How can it be fixed? Thx

Comment: Could you please share your all code used to embed your WebChat? Especially to see if you are setting an `userID`.

Comment: Thx. Just updated the problem statement with the whole bot instantiation code for the web channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in case you are actually doing this, don't pass your Direct Line authorization in your client. This is a major security issue and you open yourself up to being breached.

As for your issue, consider generating the unique `userID` and passing it in the `createDirectLine()` token call. In this way, the userID will be baked into the token and will not specifically be a function of the page. As the token *should* be unique to each user, this should help, if not solve, your user crossover issue.

If it doesn't, I would recommend removing the Direct Line direct API call from your Web Chat code. In my case, I have my own token generating server which I call from Web Chat. The token server makes the call to Direct Line when my server's API is called by Web Chat. I also generate the userID in the token server so it is baked into the token which is then returned to Web Chat for use.

If neither of these options fix your issue, then I would look closer at your external data collection, which you mentioned elsewhere.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thx! I've tried two approaches to randomize the `UserID. 1- Remove the `UserID` from the Webchat call which generates a random user ID key; 2- Generate a random `UserID` var that is passed to the WebChat.createDirectLine call. Both failed to isolate user sessions. It seems the WebChat is failing to do its work properly given random UserIDs have been defintively generate as I could see on the browser dev tool.Even when there is just one user connected to the webchat users need to hit the refresh button 2-3 times have the variable injected inside the bot app.

Comment: Case you want to see the issue in action please try the link below. Change the userName parameter as you wish. It should work well the first and the second time the conversation starts (you should see the provided name in the chat window). However, it starts mixing data after that even when accessed from different devices. https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/forms/Bit_Bot/Staging/activities.html?userName=Steven&userGenre=Male&activity=atividade2#loaded

Comment: I was just wondering if you would have a sample code snippet to share about how you've removed the Direct Line direct API call from your Web Chat code. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are assigning 'User' to `userID`, which is a static string.

> Assigning userID as a static value is not recommended since this will cause all users to share state. Please see the API [userID entry](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/API.md#userID) for more information.
>   ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat))

Remove the userID part from your snippet or change "User" to something dynamic. Otherwise the state will be shared, which means that user data is shared over all users accessing the bot.

```
userID: "User"
```

Comment: Thx!The `userID` parameter has been removed from the web bot instantiation page hence an user ID is randomly generated now.  However, it's still not working. When a new user instances the bot he sees someone else data. The moment he/she refreshes the page then he/she sees his own data. Thoughts?

Comment: I also tried making the user ID the same as the Direct Line token like `userID: token` but the issue remains. I was wondering the external data collection in my bot code might not be OK.
`if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "userName")
   {   
      studentProfile.Name = turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString();                   
      studentName = turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString()}`

Comment: Case you want to see the issue in action please try the link below.
Change the `userName` parameter as you wish.
It should work well the first and the second time the conversation starts (you should see the provided name in the chat window).
However, it starts mixing data after that even when accessed from different devices.
`https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/forms/Bit_Bot/Staging/activities.html?userName=Mick&userGenre=Male&activity=atividade2#loaded`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your support on that.
Sharing how we found a solution for the case.
First we removed the `userID: "User"` entry.
So each bot session will have its own random ID.
Then we created just one 'website-to-bot' data exchange variable.
This will make sure all data will be sent in just one browser cycle.
It seems this was causing the issue in our app.
Code snippet as follows:
`var enviromentContextData = 'studentName=&' + userName + '&studentGender=|' + userGenre + '|';
    //Bot Message Exchange Setting 
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
            dispatch({
                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                payload: {
                    name: 'enviromentContextDataPass',
                    value: enviromentContextData
                }
            });

        }
        return next(action);
    });`